# Check if User is Already logged in through window application

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows

I am creating a window application using sql database. I want to check if user already logged in through my window application if my application close without logged off data base able to detect user logged off. 
For this I am creating a table using username

```
string query = "Select * From TempDB.DBO.SysObjects Where Name='##" +     username.ToUpper() + "'";
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Before login I am checking table

```
DataTable dt = sqlda.GetQueryData("Select * From TempDB.DBO.SysObjects Where Name='##" + username.ToUpper() + "'");
```

But after login form close table also deleted.

Comment: After login form close. table is deleted?

Comment: that i have created using username

Comment: username = "'; DTOP TABLE TempDB.DBO.SysObjects; --";

Comment: Why create a whoile new table whenever the user logs in. Create one table and update it on user login and logout

Comment: @progrAmmar it's temp table that will deleted automatic when connection is closed

Comment: @AramKocharyan is exposing a possibility of SQL injection attack in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Global temp tables (##) are deleted when all users referencing that table logoff, so - in your case the tables are based on the username so they are removed.

If usernames are unique you could in turn write an entry on login to a table. In turn when the user logs off, remove the entry. You have another task running that checks for the temp table against each login record.

PS revise your query and then go watch this :) Its still very applicable to your code http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/DEV333
This is off the top of my head but revise to something like this (you'll still need to join on some login table you check)

```
string query = "Select * From TempDB.DBO.SysObjects Where Name='##' + @UserName";
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
command.Parameters.Add(
new SqlParameter("@UserName",SqlDbType.Varchar,50) {
    Value = userName.ToUpper()
);
        conn.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Also, I wasn't sure if you wanted C# code to get the logged in user to compare - but that's simply

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```